# How to show image from storage folder in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a folder in Laravel 5.3 project located in storage and it contains image files.

How can i show image from that folder?

I have all the names with

```
Storage::allFiles('images');
```

I can't access them in the usual way due to a folder permissions and i don't want to change them.
I also don't want to put the files in Public directory.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a controller function to return the image...something like:

```
public function image($file){
    $image = storage_path('images/' . $file);

    if(!File::exists( $image ))
        App::abort(404);

    // using Intervention Image package
    return Image::make($image)->response('jpg');

    // using Laravel file response
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'];
    return response()->file($image, $headers);
}
```

Of course this is very bare bones...you could spruce it up to resize on demand, examine mime types and return the correct response type based on that, etc.

Comment: And for every image i should call this function?

Comment: Yah, you'd have a route set up: `Route::get('/image/{file}', 'ImageController@image');` so when you make a GET request to `/image` it'd serve through this function.

Comment: btw, for similar use case as this, I have had really good results from the Intervention Image package. http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: What package is this? I use 
`use Faker\Provider\Image;`

and it give me error: 
`Call to undefined method Faker\Provider\Image::make()`

I just want to show image in `<img />` tag

I've seen image.intervention.io and i plan to use it later for resizing.

Comment: Oh whoops! I guess my example did use the Intervention image package...you could easily rewrite it to just deliver an image response...
`return response()->file($image, $headers);`

Comment: Ok, i used these headers
`$headers = array('Content-Type'     => 'image/png','Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$image.'"');
And now i have object BinaryFileResponse.
How i show the image in <img src='' />?

Comment: You'd add a route (like I mentioned in my first comment) to access the image by URL...use that route in your img src attribute.